# Using google endpoints gapi.client.load not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, ionic-framework, endpoints

gapi.client.load not working on iPhone device .

Its loading on android device , firefox , and safari .

Im using ionic with google app engine endpoints.

Please any help .

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'not working'.

Comment: The Endpoints Apis were not loaded to the ionic app , the callback function never called .

Answer (score 0):

Solved , 
I added the below tags to config.xml , or you may add under the platform itself

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Thanks